# How do I change the image src in my slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have this image for a slider. I want it to fade to the next image after the button is clicked. The JQuery makes the image fade in and out to make the transition cleaner when the src changes. However, the image stays the same after fading.

**Html**

```
    <button onclick = "prev()" id = "prev">Prev</button>
    <img id = "slider" src = "" height = "600px" width = "600px"/>
    <button onclick = "next()" id = "next">Next</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
    var images = ['', '', ''];
    var num = 0;

    function next() {
        var slider = $('#slider');
        num++;
        if(num >= images.length) {
            num = 0;
        }
        slider.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            slider.src = images[num];
            slider.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

    function prev() {
        var slider = $('#slider');
        num--;
        if(num < 0) {
            num = images.length-1;
        }
        slider.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            slider.src = images[num];
            slider.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }
```

I have taken out the images I tested it with as their links were too long. The three slider images would be in the JQuery "images" variable and the starting one in the image src.

Comment: `slider.attr('src', images[num]);`

Comment: log the slider.src at the bottom of your next function, and then see what it says each time you hit next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `images` is an array of image URLs, then your mistake is trying to set `slider.src` instead of `slider.attr('src, value);`.

So, use this instead:

```
slider.attr('src', images[num]);
```